# Notepad++ Find replace code blocks

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, find-and-replace

So, in my document, I have many code blocks like the one below

````
```javascript
class App extendsReact.Component{
  state ={
isLoading:true,
    users:[],
    error:null
}

render(){
<React.Fragment>
</React.Fragment>
}
}
```
````

There are multiple such code blocks in my article (they are essentially Markdown javascript syntax).

I want to find replace (or remove) such code blocks in my article.

Thus, I want to simply delete such code blocks using Find/Replace.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your question. It might be helpful to try and word it differently. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Oops...sorry....For some reason, the text I had typed went missing....I have updated it again now...Thanks for letting me know...

Comment: Great! Now your question is much clearer. I'm sure someone will be able to help you out now.

Comment: Sure....sounds good....

Comment: Are the three backticks and the word javascript part of the block to remove? Could you edi tyour question and add expected result? I guess you want to remove blocks between pair of three backticks, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: ```javascript.+?```
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]